# how to use variable with awk

Tags: linux, awk, variable

we have the following file

```
 cat  /tmp/hive.conf

      "hive-exec-log4j2" : {
        "tag" : "TOPOLOGY_RESOLVED",
        "version" : 2
      },
      "hive-interactive-env" : {
        "tag" : "TOPOLOGY_RESOLVED",
        "version" : 2
      },
      "hive-interactive-site" : {
        "tag" : "TOPOLOGY_RESOLVED",
        "version" : 2
      },
      "hive-log4j" : {
        "tag" : "TOPOLOGY_RESOLVED",
        "version" : 2
      },
      "hive-log4j2" : {
        "tag" : "TOPOLOGY_RESOLVED",
        "version" : 2
      },
```

we want to capture the line after match the "hive-log4j" from file

so we get that:

```
cat  /tmp/hive.conf |  awk  '/"hive-log4j"/{getline; print}'
        "tag" : "TOPOLOGY_RESOLVED",
```

now we want to do the same with awk and export the variable as the following

```
 val="hive-log4j"
 cat  /tmp/hive.conf |  awk -v var=$val '/"var"/{getline; print}'
```

but no output

what is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: they are absolutely different equations with different problem

Comment: It would have been better if the conf file was a complete JSON document, in which case it would have been trivial to parse it with `jq`.  It looks as if it's been proprocessed and broken in the processing.

Comment: can you please suggest an answer about this?

Comment: No, because the question is closed, and because the JSON in the configuration file is broken.  If you update the question, it will be put in the "reopen queue", and if the format of the configuration file turns out to be properly formatted JSON, I would vote to reopen it, and then suggest some `jq` command to parse it.

Comment: OK , I think it better to ask  a new question about jq

Comment: `sed -n '/hive-log4j/N;s/.*\n//p'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/.../` is a sort of regex constant, trying to match the string `"var"`, not `var`'s contents. Try

```
awk -v var=$val '$0 ~ var {getline; print}' file
```

or

```
awk -v var=$val 'match ($0, var) {getline; print}' file
```

Make sure the shell variable contains the double quotes as they are part of the pattern. If that's not possible, try

```
awk -v var=$val 'match ($0, "\"" var "\"") {getline; print}' file
```

Comment: this isnt work as I ask , because its print  both  "tag" : "TOPOLOGY_RESOLVED",
        "tag" : "TOPOLOGY_RESOLVED",  instead to print only the line under "hive-log4j"