# sed + mark line in case of marched word

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, logs, perl

we want to mark with "#" the matched line by sed or perl line liner

for example

we want to mark all lines in file that include the **DatePattern** word

```
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
```

expected output

```
#log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern
```

note - in case line already marked then it will not add another "#" before the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepending `#` to the line and also removing the `=` and whatever comes after it:

```
sed 's/^\([^#].*DatePattern\)=.*/#\1/' file
```

Alternatively, not removing the `=`:

```
sed 's/^[^#].*DatePattern/#&/' file
```

Comment: do you have another suggestion from my question on - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460642/how-to-use-variable-with-awk

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to remove the trailing date pattern (your spec is not quite clear), try

```
sed '/^[^#].*DatePattern/ s/^/#/' file
```